# How can we create Boolean-like object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to create my Boolean-like object.
But I don't want to pollute Boolean.prototype.
So I created MyBool like

```
MyBool = function (x) {
  this.value = x;
  this.valueOf = function () { return x; };
  this.toString = function () { return x; };
}
MyBool.prototype.and = function (y) {
  if (y.constructor !== MyBool) throw 'You cannot do that!';
  return this.value && y.value;
}
```

and its instances

```
mytrue = new MyBool(true);
myfalse = new MyBool(false);
```

But now, I noticed that

```
if (myfalse) {
  console.log ("myfalse is true!!!")
}
```

prints that myfalse is true!!!

(Yet +myfalse (that is [[ToNumber]] conversion) comes to falsy, thanks to valueOf)

It's obvious because only following values are falsy in ECMAScript.

```
undefined, null, false, +0, -0, NaN, ''
```

If Argument Type is Object, [[ToBoolean]] brings us true, in any case.
(see ECMA Type Conversion and Testing)

Is there any crafty way to create a falsy object?
It's ok if

```
myfalse.constructor is MyBool
(!! myfalse) is false
```

Any cheat is welcome, including ECMA5's set/get/defineProperty or anything else.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the reason you're doing this? What's wrong with Boolean?

Comment: When I want to deal with other language (A, for explanation) in JavaScript, A's false and JavaScript's false should be distinguished. And also, constructor's check leads my code to strict one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is currently possible, if you consider:

```
var myBool = new Boolean(false);
if (myBool) {
    alert('Not false');
}
```

Comment: Oh, that has no difference to false... Thanks anyway.

Comment: interesting though - if you remove the new keyword from the above example, myBool evaluates to false.

Comment: oppps... I overlooked that. Yes, that's surely interesting. Thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment, indicating you want a strict boolean. Why not use the equality operator?

```
var someBoolean = false,
    someObj = { };

if (someBoolean === false)
{
    // tada, someBoolean is a boolean AND false
}

// Returns false because someObj is NOT a boolean
if (someObj === true)
{
   ..
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Understand what `if(myfalse){}` is doing. It is checking for the *existence* of `myfalse`, not whether its true or false. In this case, `myfalse` is an object and thus exists, and thus is true.

Comment: If myfalse does not really exist, ReferenceError should be thrown. But yeah, maybe my words was too little. Thanks.